# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mySQLConnection' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, mysql

i am getting above error(UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mySQLConnection' referenced before assignment) while i tried to run the below given code.

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/home')
def index():
    return render_template('index2.html')
@app.route('/process',methods=['POST'])
def process():
    user_input=request.form['user_input']
    try:
        mySQLConnection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='python',user='root',password='xxxxxx')
        cursor = mySQLConnection.cursor(prepared=True)
        sql_select_query = "select * from data where Input LIKE %s"
        args=['%'+user_input+'%']
        cursor.execute(sql_select_query,args)
        record = cursor.fetchall()

        if (record != None):
            for row in record:
                out = row[1]
            return
```

render_template('index2.html',user_input=user_input,bot_response=out)

```
        else:
            return render_template('index2.html',user_input=user_input,bot_response='I cant understand..')

    except Error as e :
        print ("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
    finally:    
        if (mySQLConnection.is_connected()):
            mySQLConnection.close()
            cursor.close()
            print("connection is closed")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,port=5002)
```

Comment: I believe it is in `finally` block where it might be throwing this error. You should update the post with the stacktrace with the line which is causing the issue

Comment: You need to provide your full traceback for questions like this, since it's normally difficult to figure out where the error is otherwise. In this case though, it's likely because `mysql.connector.connect(...)` raises an exception and the `mySQLConnection` referenced in the finally clause is never assigned to.

Comment: @AravinthDeep what mysql package are you using??

Comment: You should remove your personal credentials from the question and change them shortly after.. Additionally, as @thebjorn pointed out your connection attempt: mysql.connector.connect(....) probably failed and threw an exception so trying to close the variable, mySQLConnection, within your finally scope wouldn't make sense since instantiation failed. To safe guard against this simply check for the variable's existence with an: if mySQLConnection in your finally clause before trying to close the connection

Comment: @NathanWright that won't work, since the error happens before the assignment (first line inside try) happens, thus the variable doesn't even _exist_ in the finally clause -- i.e. `if mySQLConnection:` will fail with the same error. It would work if the OP sets `mySQLConnection = None` _before_ the `try:`

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, for the safeguard if check you definitely need to declare mySQLConnection prior to the try block as you pointed out. I am tired and thought I put that in my comment but see I didn't, good catch